# Why can't I append a PyTorch tensor with torch.cat?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have:

```
import torch

input_sliced = torch.rand(180, 161)
output_sliced = torch.rand(180,)

batched_inputs = torch.Tensor()
batched_outputs = torch.Tensor()

print('input_sliced.size', input_sliced.size())
print('output_sliced.size', output_sliced.size())

batched_inputs = torch.cat((batched_inputs, input_sliced))
batched_outputs = torch.cat((batched_outputs, output_sliced))

print('batched_inputs.size', batched_inputs.size())
print('batched_outputs.size', batched_outputs.size())
```

This outputs:

```
input_sliced.size torch.Size([180, 161])
output_sliced.size torch.Size([180])

batched_inputs.size torch.Size([180, 161])
batched_outputs.size torch.Size([180])
```

I need the `batched` ones to append, but the `torch.cat` isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is working exactly as expected. Is your code complete? Is `batched_*` supposed to be an empty tensor? What is the expected output?

Comment: I want batched to be [1, 180,161]

Comment: There is no clean alternative. I assume you wanna do this over and over, so the question is: do you need intermediate "cat"s to result in a `Tensor` or only the final `batched_*`?

Comment: Correct - I want to do it over and over. I only need the final batched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're doing it in a loop, I'd say it is better to do like this:

```py
import torch

batch_input, batch_output = [], []
for i in range(10):  # assuming batch_size=10
    batch_input.append(torch.rand(180, 161))
    batch_output.append(torch.rand(180,))

batch_input = torch.stack(batch_input)
batch_output = torch.stack(batch_output)

print(batch_input.shape)   # output: torch.Size([10, 180, 161])
print(batch_output.shape)  # output: torch.Size([10, 180])
```

If you know the resulting `batch_*` shape *a priori*, you can preallocate the final `Tensor` and simply assign each sample into their corresponding positions in the batch. It would be more memory efficient.